# Verificando dias restantes entre a data atual e prazo para contato

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Boa tarde pessoal, conforme o código abaixo, não estou conseguindo verificar os dias restantes entre a $data e o $prazocontato.

```
$consulta = mysql_query("
        SELECT s.id_cliente, p.nome_servicos, s.data, s.prazocontato, s.email, s.vaifazerservicos 
        FROM dadoscliente AS s 
        INNER JOIN servicos2 AS p 
        ON p.id_servicos = s.vaifazerservicos 
        ORDER BY s.id_cliente DESC 
        LIMIT $start, $limite");

        while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)) {
        $id_cliente = $linha['id_cliente'];
        $nome_servicos = $linha['nome_servicos'];
        $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($linha['data']));
        $prazocontato = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($linha['prazocontato']));

    $ValorUm = $data;
    $ValorDois = $prazocontato;
    $prazo = $ValorUm + $ValorDois;
        ?>        

<?php if($prazo == 0){
            echo "
<tr>
    <td>$id_cliente</td>
    <td>$nome_servicos</td>
    <td>$data</td>
    <td>$prazocontato</td>
    <td style='color:blue;'><b>ENCERRA HOJE!</b></td>
    <td><a href='editar.php?id_cliente=$id_cliente'><img src='img/editar3.png' title='Editar'></a></td>
</tr> 

    ";
}elseif($prazo < 0){
    echo "
<tr>
    <td>$id_cliente</td>
    <td>$nome_servicos</td>
    <td>$data</td>
    <td>$prazocontato</td>
    <td style='color:red;'><b>ENCERRADO!</b></td>
    <td style='visibility: hidden;'><a href='editar.php?id_cliente=$id_cliente'><img src='img/editar3.png' title='Editar'></a></td>
</tr>   

    ";
}else{
    echo "
<tr>
    <td>$id_cliente</td>
    <td>$nome_servicos</td>
    <td>$data</td>
    <td>$prazocontato</td>
    <td>$prazo Dia(s)</td>
    <td><a href='editar.php?id_cliente=$id_cliente'><img src='img/editar3.png' title='Editar'></a></td>
</tr> 
    ";
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é o problema? tem sinal de menos perdido nessa linha `$prazo = - $ValorUm + $ValorDois;`

Comment: Descreva melhor o seu problema... além do que o colega @rray descreveu, não consegui identificar mais nada que possa ser problema.

Comment: $ValorUm = $date; De onde vem a variavel $date?

Comment: Vem do banco de dados @MagicHat, acabei de editar ele, na realidade ;e $data.

Comment: A coluna "Faltam" não vai sempre mostrar os mesmos valores? Do jeito que está aí dá a entender que é tipo um countdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Tente isso

```
$data_inicial = new DateTime($linha['data']); 
$data_final = new DateTime($linha['prazo_contato']); 
$diferenca = $data_inicial->diff( $data_final ); 
$diferenca = $diferenca->format('%d days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está colocando

```
$ValorUm = $date;
```

A variavel que você criou é datA e não datE, você está colocando com "e" ao invés de "a" no final e por isso está dando errado.

```
$ValorUm = $data;
```

Considerando que você precisa da diferença entre as duas (para saber quantos dias falta entre uma e outra) faça

```
 $data_inicial = $linha['data'];
    $data_final = $linha['prazo_contato'];

     // Calcula a diferença em segundos entre as datas
     $diferenca = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_inicial);

     //Calcula a diferença em dias 
     $prazo = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24)); //floor(); é usado para arredondar
```

Comment: acabei de editar @Diéfani, mas o resultado continua o mesmo

Comment: @MauroSantos o seu código está exibindo as outras variaveis? Digo, o id e o nome dos serviços aparece corretamente impressos na tela?

Comment: Sim @Diéfani... só não estou conseguindo somar a data entre os mês atual e o mês seguinte, os valores no mês atual estão somando corretamente. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42587/discussion-between-magichat-and-mauro-santos

Comment: Só pra me situar direito, você tem a data e a data de prazo de contato, você quer saber quantos dias faltam para o prazo? Porque eu estava pensando, o certo não seria calcular a diferença entre elas?

Comment: Você esta correta @Diéfani, estou querendo saber quantos dias faltas para o prazo.

Comment: @MauroSantos olhe a minha edição de resposta, tente fazer e veja se funciona.

Comment: ta dando erro aqui $diferenca = strtotime($data_final) - strtotime($data_inicial);

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43025/discussion-between-mauro-santos-and-diefani-favareto-piovezan).